# How to iterate std::list<AbstractType*>

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have this list:

```
std::list<AbstractType*> myList;
```

How can I iterate it, grab each object and perform some of their operations as normal instances?

In Java, it would be something like:

```
foreach(AbstractType object in myList)
    object.method();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using C++11, see the answers by @Mankarse or @billz.

If you are using C++98, then you should do it like in the following example (or through an equivalent `while` loop:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<AbstractType*> l;
    // ...
    for (std::list<AbstractType*>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
    {
        (*i)->DoSomething();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

As @Mankarse pointed out in a comment, in C++98 you can also use BOOST_FOREACH:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(AbstractType* pObject, l)
{
    pObject->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: In C++98, you can also use [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/foreach.html) for java-like syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ code is almost identical:

```
for (AbstractType* object: myList)
    object->method();
```

Comment: Any way to do it using the std library?

Answer (score 0):

Using C++ STL you have an iterator for this. After you defined it you use begin() and end() methods.

Answer (score 0):

If not using C++ 11, you can make a free function acting on `AbstractType` and call it with `std::for_each`:

```
void doSomething(AbstractType& object) {
    object.doSomething();
}

int main() {
    // ...
    std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
                  doSomething);
    // ...
}
```